# Android AIR In-app Purchase Flash CS6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, in-app-purchase, flash-cs6

I am building an android app from Adobe AIR and Adobe flash CS6. I want to add In-app purchase in my app. I know that can be done using native extensions and I found one free extension here 
https://github.com/pozirk/AndroidInAppPurchase
but I do not know how and where to integrate the coding in my flash timeline. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this might help: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-billing-ane.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at our getting started tutorial here:

https://distriqt.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/181029-using-native-extensions

It should at least get you going with the basic concepts of including an ANE in your project.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find free adobe air native extensions http://www.devactionscript.com/